# Single Sign On and NFS permissions on Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, nfs, single-sign-on

Like many, I've been trying to move away from Microsoft Active Directory + CIFS file sharing into a custom LDAP solution + NFSv4. All the workstations here run Windows 7, and I have set up the following so far:

- [pGina](http://pgina.org) is installed in every workstation and Logging into my custom OpenLDAP server works fine. The latest beta version of pGina even allows the user to change their password!
- After activating NFS for Windows 7, I am able to successfuly mount an NFS share, although the server treats me like *nobody/nogroup* instead of giving me what is rightfully mine!

Now, the last item has been a big source of headaches for the last two days, because up-to-date, thorough information is hard to find. Here is the info that I gathered:

- **idmapd.conf** is only used if you use the *krb5* - or similar - authentication method to mount the NFS share. This means that you need to set up *Kerberos*, not a trivial task.
- Windows needs an Identity Mapping Service to map local accounts to Unix accounts. There is some very good info on this [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2012/10/09/nfs-identity-mapping-in-windows-server-2012.aspx), but I've failed to find anyone that managed to do this on the internet. I've found an [user with a problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21e36fa3-a293-4e3d-a006-ff395c003c6d/windows-2012-server-for-nfs-ldapquery-for-identitymapping-includes-domain-in?forum=windowsserverpreview), but without solution (and I fear it might happen to me).
- It seems like there is (still?) [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1088154) on Ubuntu 12.04's distribution of nfs-utils when configuring *idmapd* to retrieve mappings from a LDAP server (umich_ldap translation method). This is *really important* because it allows for centralized account management, one of the whole points of doing all this.

Now, before I delve into Kerberos and Windows Identity Mapping and apply Ubuntu patches and find even more problems, my questions are:
**Has anyone gone down this road and managed to accomplish this successfuly? Should I head another direction? Where can I find some decent, thorough material on all this?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [FreeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org) and it's [Kerberos cross-realm trust](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Trusts) with Active Directory. How this works:

1. Install FreeIPA server as the Linux machines domain controller
2. Create cross-realm trust between FreeIPA and AD (*trust-add* command) - [related testing instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_freeipav3_ad_trust)
3. [Configure a Kerberos protected NFS share](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/FreeIPA_Guide/kerb-nfs.html) on the FreeIPA server or on another machine which is a FreeIPA client
4. Mount that share either in Windows or Linux machines
5. Profit!

I was playing with that recently and I was able to mount a Kerberos protected NFS share to Windows Server 2012 (after I installed the Unix extension), with Kerberos and single sign on.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but one of the greatest concerns here is to stay away from AD, mostly due to licensing costs

Comment: Please ignore the last comment, I've just realized that the links you provided show how to set up AD with Samba. I would still rather go with a custom LDAP + NFSv4 solution (although if I don't manage to make it that way, I'll look into Samba)

Comment: FreeIPA is a LDAP-based Identity Management solution, it is not so related to Samba. Only the FreeIPA-AD cross-realm trust part of FreeIPA uses some parts of the Samba libraries to communicate with AD, but it does not configure parts like Samba4 DC or similar - it is all LDAP.

Comment: BTW with FreeIPA being an identity management solution there should not be any added costs as the Linux hosts would be enrolled with FreeIPA, not AD - i.e. no additional AD license needed.

Comment: I didn't know FreeIPA and it looks really interesting! Thanks for the info. However, I would still rather stay away from Samba, even if it is only doing a tiny part of the job - this is now almost a personal matter.